# How to add a PDF to html page, merged in a single view

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I want to add a pdf to a html page to print those two files like a single, I mean the pdf contains the page 1 and the html from the 2 to the end.

https://jsfiddle.net/BernardoBJ/u7wogfvn/

```
<html>
    <body>
        <I want to add a pdf here>
        <html content>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need this to send to print the page and merge the pdf with the html view.
I already try to add the pdf like a source or embed, but this doesn't works.
I think that I need convert the pdf to html or something before to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/) , it's a pure HTML5/JS solution with no plugins required. Otherwise you could look into doing something as simple as:

```
<embed src="http://example.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>
```

Just host the PDF somewhere and set the src accordingly

Comment: Printing the the html page wont include the pdf in both examples right?

Comment: With embed tag the pdf is added like a object. I need this to send to print the page and merge the pdf with the html view, I think that I need convert the pdf to html or something before to add it.

Comment: @BernardoBorunda - Yeah, I think the original question is too broad.